# How to provide submodule functions through shared libraries while extending Jenkins Pipeline DSL

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

When extending DSL, I can extending say this way:

```
boo {
   var1='var'
}
```

But I want to do extend DSL this way:

```
boo.RunBooWithFoo('var1')
```

Can someone provide an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a file `vars/boo.groovy` in the shared library and put that function there.

```
def RunBooWithFoo(arg) {
    //your logic
}
```

Then in pipeline you can use it this way

```
@Library('shared-library-name') _
boo.RunBooWithFoo('var1')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a Shared Library Extension documentation you would suggest in addition to the one in jenkin.io

Comment: @RijoSimon I am not aware of any other. I think [jenkins.io](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) has quite enough to understand shared libraries.

Comment: I added my groovy folder to the resources folder of my plugin as exampled in this project: https://github.com/jenkinsci/simple-build-for-pipeline-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/dsl .  But this doesn't really load the share library. Atleast not implicitly. What am I doing wrong here. How do I ship the shared library with the plugin, so that users who install the library can also make use of the DSL extension?

Comment: @RijoSimon you shouldn't use custom plugin for this. All you need is just a separate repository with `vars` and/or `src` folders See this [example](https://cleverbuilder.com/articles/jenkins-shared-library/)